# Python How to send POST requests with parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I Want to make script that send a post request with custom parameters to change the time table for another value And then print the output.

The Website is [THIS](http://tikah.iscool.co.il/default.aspx)
I've written the following code, but it gives me not the answer i wanted, It says the value is 14  however i sent a request for 42..

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://tikah.iscool.co.il/default.aspx", data={'dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList': "42"})
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: You're sending data fine. It's not clear why you're expecting that response, though. For example, how do you know a POST request with that payload does what you want?

Comment: Is this a valid key dnn$ctr6707$TimeTableView$ClassesList in the POST data ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Inspect Element on the website shows that a post request used in the form

Comment: @VishvajitPathak yes

Comment: You should look at the network tab for the POST request. Then you can right click, copy as cURL, and paste into your question here